# How to connect an iphone to a Honda Civic?

Tags: honda, civic, audio

I hope this isn't off topic but I am really clueless about cars. I just got my license recently and have been struggling to connect my iPhone to my car. I own a 2011 Honda Civic. I bought this cable from Amazon:

[http://www.amazon.com/Scosche-IU3-5RC-3-5mm-Retractable-Cable/dp/B000ALY22Q/ref=cm_srch_res_rtr_1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000ALY22Q)

But I don't see any place were I can connect it on the dashboard. Is this something that can be connected to the Civic out of the box or does additional equipment need to be installed?

If it can be connected right away where exactly do I plug it in, I see no hole for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you say which version/year your Civic is?

Recent Civics got an AUX IN (audio Auxiliary in) port where you can plug it in. This is normally on driver's side, bottom of the dash.

Otherwise you'll have to buy an extension panel (I'm not sure this is the 'official name for it') which replaces your CD changer. What it does it, simply connects to the audio channel your CD changer uses to connect to the sound system in the vehicle and send signals coming from your phone.

I have the same issue with my Nissan Primera P12 2001. It has a CD changer (which can read mini-CDs and stuff), and a DVD changer but no audio in port. I'm planning to swap the CD changer to one of these panels so I can plug my phone in for internet radio .etc.

Comment: In case anyone else has the same issue, I found the AUX cable on my 2011 Civic right under the power adapter. All I had to do then was connect the cable I bought to the iphone and the AUX input and press the "AUX" button which is on the same level as the radio and cd buttons. And the IpHone music started playing in the speakers!